How does it work (can I edit) the COALESCED_INT.BIN file (PS3)?
I have been trying to modify one Drakengard 3 (UE3-PS3) text to translate it; the problem is that the tool I use to translate only modifies the texts in UTF16 of the game files, but there are also texts encoded in UTF32 that the tool does not modify but the game reads, and therefore it is not applied in the game.
I have a way to modify them manually, but this breaks the file in a certain way and is very tedious.
The Russians did something weird; they got the game to read all the text in UTF-16 encoding and forget about UTF-32 encoding. So I want to know in which file/place it is determined what kind of encoding to read at each moment, and I read in several places that COALESCED saves many variables of the game, and I have a suspicion that here could be such a configuration.
